# How to change border color of a Jface Dialog(or TitleAreaDialog)?

Tags: eclipse, dialog, jface, titleareadialog

I'm tring to change the  border color of a TitleAreaDialog.

But after research found no support for this attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled in the class [JFaceColors](https://www.cct.lsu.edu/~rguidry/ecl31docs/api32/index.html?org/eclipse/jface/resource/JFaceColors.html) You should add a IPropertyChangeListener to detect when any of these colors change. Refer also to the [ColorRegistry](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/floggy/3rd/org/eclipse/jface/3.3.2.M20080207-0800/jface-3.3.2.M20080207-0800-javadoc.jar!/index.html?org/eclipse/jface/resource/JFaceColors.html), where you can add colors.